# Table Creation in Stata: Creating Multiple Row Variable Headers

Tags: latex, stata

I am using `esttab` to create tables in Stata and rendering them in LaTeX and want to split an `mgroups` variable header so that it is stretched across two rows (i.e. basically creating two `mgroups`). This is so I can create a table that looks like this: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxImV.png).

Since I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, I have for now combined the two 'subject type' and 'teacher gender' heading row, in the above table, into a single row using the following command:

```
esttab Classics_M_M Classics_F_M Classics_M_F Classics_F_F Science_M_M Science_F_M Science_M_F Science_F_F EScience_M_M EScience_F_M EScience_M_F EScience_F_F using "$dir/Graphs_Tables/tableA17.tex", p stats(N fixed1 fixed2 fixed3 fixed4 fixed5 fixed6 fixed7 fixed8, fmt(%9.0gc) labels("\vspace{0.7em} Observations \vspace{0.7em}" "Teacher Characteristics" "Previous Year Test Scores" "Grade FE" "Year FE" "Track FE" "Subject FE" "Class FE" "Student FE")) mlabels(Male Female Male Female Male Female Male Female Male Female Male Female, begin(Student Gender)) varlabels(tv "Teacher VA") mgroups("Classics Male" "Classics Female" "Science Male" "Science Female" "Exact Science Male" "Exact Science Female", pattern(1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0) begin(Subject and Teacher Gender) prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) suffix(}) span erepeat(\cmidrule(lr){@span})) f nomtitles booktabs drop(experience lag_mod _cons) nolines posthead(\midrule) replace
```

I have tried things like using two `mgroups()` commands and including `"\par"` in the titles to split them on two rows but no luck! I am hoping someone on here has an idea!

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1629748-table-creation-creating-multiple-row-variable-headers It's always courteous to mention cross-posting.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a Latex question wrapped in a Stata question.

The Latex question: How to get the contents of a cell to wrap.
Variations of this are discussed often on tex.stackexchange, here are a couple.

1. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54069/table-with-text-wrapping

   - Uses \newcommand.
2. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells

   - Just nests a table within a table.

The Stata question: Is there an easy way to do this from the esttab command? #2 above provides a relatively easy way to do this.

"Simply" replace: `mgroups("Classics Male")`

with `mgroups("\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Classics \\ Male\end{tabular}")`

This is just an answer to [#2 above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40562) dropped into your esttab statement, so that answer is certainly recommended reading.

Comment: This approach has the advantage of not relying on anything outside of the `esttab` call. The `\newcommand` approach and other using `\shortstack` and [`\makecell`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501507) have the advantage of a shorter `mgroup` label, but will break if you pipe the table to a document that doesn't define or load the command.